# How to fix parent style not full loaded in child theme?

Tags: wordpress

The parent stylesheet is not fully loaded inside my child theme. How can I solve this?

This is my current code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cleaningservices_enqueue_styles');

function cleaningservices_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'cleaning-services-style' for the Cleaning Services theme.

    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_parent_theme_file_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to append `style.css` to the result of `get_parent_theme_file_uri`, but add it as a parameter, like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cleaningservices_enqueue_styles');

function cleaningservices_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'cleaning-services-style' for the Cleaning Services theme.

    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ));
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
```